# Generating permutations of a string in a range

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

I am looking for an extremely efficient way to generate all possible permutations of a string (or alphabet), where the permutation length it bounded below and above by two variables `(i, j)`.

So far I have been able to generate permutations a number of ways, e.g...

```
void swap(char *x, char *y){
    char w;
    w = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = w;
}

void permute(char *str, int start, int n){
    int i;

    if(start == n-1)
        printf("%s\n", str);
    else
        for(i = start; i < n; i++){
            swap(str+i, str+start);
            permute(str, start+1, n);
            swap(str+i, str+start);
        }
}
```

... but no algorithm I have found so far will efficiently limit the length of the resulting strings. An example of this would be if the alphabet was defined as `abcde` and `i = 2`, `j = 4`... this would yield permutations such as `ab`, `bac`, `dcea`, but NOT `a`, `edcba`, and since the algorithm is not computing combinations, it would also not yield strings like `aab`.

Comment: What do you mean by permutation lenght ? An example ?

Comment: What's actually wrong with your solution ?

Comment: @hivert, the explanation is now in the question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, my solution does not allow me to have an alphabet larger than the target string size.

Comment: @Matt Olan: Thanks ! Could the string contains repeated letters ? If yes wha't the result of "aaab" 2 4 ?

Comment: Your program generates all permutations of a string. If your string is "ABC" then e.g. "ACB", "BAC", "CBA" are permutations of the string. But "A" is not neither is "AA". Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) for a definition of **permutation**.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know the "permutations" I am looking for are not the same length of the original string, and technically not a true permutation. This being said, I think it is the closest description of what I am looking for, as explained in the question.

Comment: @hivert The original string (or alphabet) can have repeats, which would result in the possibility of repeats in the permutations. However, if the alphabet is `abcd`, this could not yield `aacb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply passing the minimum and maximum length into the function, and printing the string when `start` is between the two?

Code:

```
void permute(char *str, int start, int n, int minLength, int maxLength)
{
    int i;

    if (start >= minLength)
    {
        char temp = str[start]; // store the character, so we don't lose it
        str[start] = 0; // 0x00 - end of string
        printf("%s\n", str);
        str[start] = temp;
    }

    if (start == maxLength)
        return;

    for (i = start; i < n; i++)
    {
        swap(str+i, str+start);
        permute(str, start+1, n, minLength, maxLength);
        swap(str+i, str+start);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/iiT23k).

---

If there are duplicates in the data, and you want to prevent duplicate permutations, all you need to do is:

- Sort the letters to start so any repeated characters are next to each other
- Don't do anything if the last character was the same as this one. This can be done by simply adding the following code to the beginning of the for-loop:

  ```
  if (i != start && str[i] == str[i-1])
      continue;
  ```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/JStbUm).

Comment: Depending on the order of generation, would this not waste time with permutations that are out of range?

Comment: It will stop when it gets to `maxLength`, so it won't waste time with permutations longer than that (if that's what you're referring to).

Comment: I lied :( Turns out that this will generate duplicates. For example... using "hello" as str, will generate two occurrences of `ohel, oehl, hoel, heol, eohl, ehol`.